# Python Regular Expression Date YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Tags: python, regex

Example Data:
Site,Account,email Address,Date
01,123456789,test@gmail.com,2017-12-12 10:00:24

I want to use an if statement which will strip out all invalid dates to an exclusion file and write all valid dates to a success file using regular expression.

```
for row in reader:
                    SITE = row[0].strip()
                    SITE = SITE.rjust(2, '0')
                    ACCOUNT = row[1].strip()
                    ACCOUNT = ACCOUNT.rjust(9, '0')
                    EMAIL = row[2].strip()
                    DATE = row[3].strip()
                    DATA = (SITE, ACCOUNT,EMAIL,DATE)
                    if not re.match("^[0-9]+$", DATE):
                            csvWriter3.writerow(DATA)
                    else:
                            csvWriter.writerow(DATA)
                            csvWriter2.writerow(DATA)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use regex for that. Use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). If it fails then you know that the date is in the wrong format (and even an invalid date in a valid format as @JonClements elaborated in the comment).

```
from datetime import datetime

try:
    datetime.strptime(DATE, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # or date_object = datetime.strptime(DATE, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # if you need the actual date object later
except ValueError:
    pass  # handle invalid date
else:
    pass  # handle valid date
```

Comment: Yeah... not only if it's not in the correct format but also if it's an invalid date in a valid format...